# Is it possible to route from HTTPS to SFTP with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, https, apache-camel, sftp

I want to download a CSV file from HTTPS server and send it to SFTP server and I'm using HTTP4 componenet for HTTPS. Is it possible to combine two routes?

```
{
    from("https4:www.00000/00/downloads/sdn.csv?")
    .to("sftp://0000000/myhome/?fileName=${file:name}&\");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with a timer or other "trigger" in order to "get" the file from an http site. By default, 'from uri="http.."' tells Camel to *listen* on an http port.  Also, a Polling Consumer may be helpful.

ref: http://camel.apache.org/timer.html

ref: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

Pseudo code:

```
from("timer:...")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
.to("https4:www....")  <-- Note: the return is now the ${body} in Camel
.to("sftp://...")
```

Comment: well, actualy I need to transfer a file from https server to a sftp server , do I need get method for that?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more descriptive pseudo-code

Comment: that helps, Do I need to add https4 to my context ?I have it in pom.xml as deppendency .